# Ansible: Pbrun not able to execute

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have the below inventory file

```
[server]
abc.com
[server:vars]
ansible_user="user1"
ansible_ssh_pass="pwd"
ansible_pbrun_exe="pbrun"
ansible_pbrun_password="pqa"
ansible_pbrun_user="root"
```

and the playbook file

```
---
- name: Upgrade Java Version to all the hosts
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: run simple command
      shell: java -version 2>&1 | grep version | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/"//g'
      register: javav
      
    - name: remove the currently installed java
      become: true
      become_method: "pbrun"
      shell: |
        mv /usr/bin/java  ~/bckup_java_exe
        mv /usr/java/ ~/bckup_java
```

Now when I run the ansible playbook it connects to the ssh host and is also able to run the `java -version ..` command successfully but not able to run the `mv` command as it needs `pbrun`

when I remove `become: true` from playbook it shows Permission error

`````
```
: Permission denied", "mv: cannot move `/usr/java/' to
````
`````

And when I do not remove `become: true` it gives some other error, and it is not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i have found is below

```
  become: "yes"
  become_method: "pbrun"
  become_user: "root"
  become_flags: "sa"
```

as we ran pbrun sa -u root

also do not forget to set `ansible_become_pass` into inventory file or `--ask-become-pass`

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not see that you have set `become_method: pbrun` anywhere. This is required.

Comment: I have added become_method: pbrun into the playbook but still getting error permission denied

Comment: if I have added become true and become_method: pbrun then

Comment: "module_stdout": "No user specified!\r\r\nSorry, your request is not allowed: No access configured on  Request rejected by pbmasterd on .\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 127}  I get this error

Comment: @RajarshiDas It looks like you don't have access, then. You should talk to the appropriate people in your company to get the correct access.

Comment: Thanks for comments but in manually I can able to access root through pbrun

Comment: Michael the solution is become_flags: 'sa'. I  ran pbrun sa -u root but thanks for your help

Comment: @RajarshiDas You should tick your own answer because it contains the correct solution.